# CGPoint x on SKSpriteNode not working correctly(Half of Node out of screen)

Tags: position, swift, sprite-kit, cgpoint

I'm actually developing a game in Swift SpriteKit.

I set the position of a SKSpriteNode:

```
skPart1.position = CGPointMake(0, 100)
```

So the node should start at the very left window-edge.

```
    |-------------------------|   
    |-------------------------|
    |-------------------------|
    |-------------------------|
    |==========|--------------|
    |==========|--------------|
    |==========|--------------|
```

But in reality half of my SKSpriteNode is outside of the screen:

```
     |-------------------------|   
     |-------------------------|
     |-------------------------|
     |-------------------------|
==========|--------------------|
==========|--------------------|
==========|--------------------|
```

I've read the same problem on stackoverflow, but the only solution provided there was, to set the scaleMode to AspectFit.
I've figured out, that it works with SKShapeNode. But why not in SKSpriteNode?
And I've alreay tried that.

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SKSpriteNode  has an anchorPoint property that defaults to the center of the image, which is why half of the sprite is off the left side of the screen.

You can adjust the anchorPoint so that it behaves like your `SKShapeNode` with the anchor in the bottom left. Try this :

```
skPart1.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0,0);
```

I know you have accepted an answer, however this is the ideal way to handle the situation and it's why the property exists.

Answer (score 1):

I think this actually depends on what you're using as your SKShapeNode. If you're using a rectangle, then the point you give it will be the lower left corner of the rectangle. But if you use a SKShapeNode circle, it'll drop the circle centered on that point you give it, and you'll see very similar behavior to the SKSpriteNode.

The SKSpriteNode is using the center of the image as the point it places your sprite at, and so when you're placing your node at (0, 100), exactly half of it is being draw to the left of the screen.

If you want your sprite to be drawn as far left as possible, but completely on the screen, you should be able to accomplish this by offsetting for one half of the sprite's width.

```
skPart1.position = CGPoint(x: skPart1.size.width / 2, y: 100)
```